# get cluster items issue on google map v3 in android native environment

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

In android using GMAp V3 , trying to access all items in a cluster , when i using cluster.getSize() its returning fine but cannot get all items or markers in the cluster on particular cluster click event , here i attaching part of my code block

```
private void loadClusterPopupList(Cluster cluster, ClusterManager clusterManager){
  Collection<Marker> ff =    clusterManager.getClusterMarkerCollection().getMarkers();



    while (cluster.getItems().iterator().hasNext()) {
        Log.w("LT_LL:", cluster.getItems().iterator().next().toString());
    }
```

}

Comment: ok, finally I got solution,

Comment: the Solution is:

 private void loadClusterPopupList(Cluster<ClusterPopupList> cluster,ClusterManager clusterManager){
 for (ClusterPopupList p: cluster.getItems()) {
            // Draw 4 at most.
            Log.e("PP",p.getPosition().toString());
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out it's Solution:

```
private void loadClusterPopupList(Cluster<ClusterPopupList> cluster,
ClusterManager clusterManager){for (ClusterPopupList p: cluster.getItems()){
            // Draw 4 at most.
            Log.e("PP",p.getPosition().toString());}}
```